# PostgreSQL Dollar quoting and SELECT LIKE

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to use dollar-quoted strings within a SELECT ... LIKE?

i.e.

```
SELECT "firstName", "lastName" FROM person WHERE "firstName" LIKE '%$xx$j$xx$'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE "firstName" LIKE $xx$j$xx$
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE "firstName" LIKE $xx$j$xx$%;
```

The first returns no rows, because I have no names that start with $xx$j$xx$. 
 The second returns no rows.  The third returns a syntax error at the semicolon (due to the hanging %)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LIKE wildcard needs to be part of the string, not *after* the string:

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE "firstName" LIKE $xx$j%$xx$;
```

or simpler

```
SELECT * FROM person WHERE "firstName" LIKE 'j%';
```

Comment: Works for me!  I'll accept in a moment (StackOverflow has me on a time delay right now)